# Brute force alphanumeric passwords between 1 to 7 characters long with ZAP

Tags: passwords, brute-force, zap

In BurpSuite, you can brute force a password of any length and any character set (in my case, alphanumeric passwords between 1 to 7 characters long). How does one do it in OWASP ZAP, without actually generating a password list containing alphanumeric passwords between 1 to 7 characters long?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

With ZAP you could do this using a `Regex (*Experimental*)` payload, such as `[a-z0-9]{7}`.

Ex (passwords/strings length 7):
[image]
[image]

You'd probably have to create multiple fuzzers to handle the length variation, although doing passwords <6 char is probably pointless. If you're target accepts passwords that are super short they have other issues.

## Option 2

You could create a [script payloadgenerator](https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/main/payloadgenerator), based on something like: https://github.com/noamsauerutley/string-permutations

### Math

Keep in mind this [works out](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/passes) to (`36^7`) `==` `78,364,164,096` possible passwords.
If you had 20 threads going once per second, that's `3,918,208,205` seconds or like `~124` years.